# Automatic updating of column

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, update-query

Have come across a problem in Qgis (3.16.9)

I have a geometry layer (A) with lines and a csv file (B) with prices. I have a joint so the price from the csv file (B) comes over in the geometry file (A).
I have created an attribute form in (A) on a column (length-price) that multiplies the length by the price

"length" * "unit price"

When I update the price in the csv table, the column (length-price) is not recalculated. If I change the geometry it changes.

Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Have you tried creating a virtual field?

Comment: no - and I would like to avoid it, as - as I understand it - it is stored in the qgs file and with large amounts of data makes QGIS slow - but I could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

Open the feature table of the `csv layer` and press the refresh button. On your join you should deselect the Option `Cache join layer in virtual memory`.

Comment: tried the advice from Erik about virtual field - and immediately it works without problems - thanks Erik